# Goodstein's sequences and theorem.

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, ordinals

I was wondering if anyone would be able to provide me with any textbooks that discuss the Goodstein sequence and the Goodstein theorem and which provide a proof also?
Thanks.

Comment: You should advise your Readers where your interest and understanding of this material is.  Have you read the corresponding Wikipedia article?  Are you asking for help in filling in gaps there, or are you wanting to know about some related developments?  As currently phrased the Question seems pretty broad.

Comment: If you happen to understand German, it can be found in Martin Ziegler's "Mathematische Logik" on p. 61 as an exercise with a key hint. (It's still an advanced exercise, I'd say, but it's certainly doable with some basic knowledge about ordinals.) That's how I learned about it, anyways.

Comment: I don't understand German unfortunately, but thanks. I'm just looking for a proof of the theorem and the statement itself

Comment: James M. Henle's "An Outline of Set Theory" has a chapter on Goodstein's theorem. It doesn't contain a proof, but gives a lot of pointers into the right direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very nice introduction to this area is

> [MR0891258(88g:03084)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=891258). Simpson, Stephen G. *Unprovable theorems and fast-growing functions*. In **[Logic and combinatorics (Arcata, Calif., 1985)](https://doi.org/10.1090/conm/065)**, 359–394, Contemp. Math., 65, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1987.

Simpson describes the paper as inspired by the question of whether there could be "a comprehensive, self-contained discipline of finite combinatorial mathematics". He argues that the incompleteness results he describes (the unprovability of Goodstein's theorem in Peano arithmetic being one example) indicate that the answer is no. The paper is expository and assumes almost no background from logic. For instance, it introduces ordinals and provides many intuitions for several of the results it describes. I think it is a joy to read. I actually really like the collection it appears in. Many of the papers in it (although in general much more technical) deal with similar results (unprovability of Hydra-Hercules games, variants of Kruskal's tree theorem, etc).

One of the results Simpson's presents is Goodstein's, and the paper contains a decent sketch (together with references to papers proving its unprovability in $\mathsf{PA}$).

Specifically on Goodstein's theorem, you may also enjoy reading the paper *[The termite and the tower](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/sladekgoodstein.pdf)* by Will Sladek. Will wrote it while an undergraduate student at Caltech, as part of their *Mathematical writing* course; I served as a mentor through the write-up process. I think the metaphor in the title is a great way of describing Goodstein's theorem.

While Will was working on the paper, I thought it would be nice to include some numbers illustrating how long some Goodstein sequences take to terminate. This ballooned into a short paper of my own,

> [MR2585906(2011c:03139)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2585906). Caicedo, Andrés Eduardo. *[Goodstein's function](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/goodsteins.pdf)*. Rev. Colombiana Mat. **41** (2007), no. 2, 381–391.

In the paper I present a formula for computing Goodstein's function, the map that to each $n$ assigns the number of steps that it takes the Goodstein sequence starting at $n$ to terminate.

Recall that the sequence is defined as follows: Let $n\ge2$. The base-$n$ expansion of $m\in\mathbb N$ is the unique way of writing $m$ as a sum $\sum_{j=0}^k a_j n^k$ where each $a_j$ is a base-$n$ "digit" (a number in $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$. The complete base-$n$ expansion is the result of iterating this representation, by also writing in base $n$ all the exponents $k$ of powers of $n$ in the expansion of $m$, and all the exponents in the expansion of these exponents, and so on.

An example I give in the paper is $m=266$. Its base-$2$ expansion is $266=2^8 + 2^3 + 2^1$. To obtain the complete base-$2$ expansion, we write $8$ as $2^3=2^{2^1+1}$, and $3$ as $2^1+1$, thus
 $$ 266= 2^{2^{2+1}} + 2^{2+1} + 2 $$ where, for clarity, I am just writing $2$ instead of $2^1$ throughout.

The change of base function $R_n$ assigns to each $m\in\mathbb N$ the result of replacing with $n+1$ each $n$ in the complete base-$n$ expansion of $m$.

For instance, $$ R_2(266)=3^{3^{3+1}}+3^{3+1}+3=443426488243037769948249630619149892887. $$

The Goodstein sequence starting at $m$ is the sequence $(m)_k$ where $(m)_1=m$ and $$(m)_{k+1}=\begin{cases} R_{k+1}((m)_k)-1&\text{if }(m)_k>0,\\0&\text{if }(m)_k=0.\end{cases}$$

That the sequence terminates means that $(m)_k=0$ for some $k$. Goodstein's theorem is the statement that the sequence terminates for any $m$, and Goodstein's function $\mathcal G$ assigns to $m$ the least $k$ such that $(m)_k=0$.

The "tower" in Will's paper refers to the stack of exponentials in the complete base-$n$ representation of a number. The "termite" is the $-1$, the small bit we chip away at each step. The usual proof of Goodstein's theorem
replaces at each step $k$ each $k$ in the complete base-$k$ representation of the number with an $\omega$, thus associating to each step in the sequence an ordinal number written in Cantor normal form. What one checks is that these ordinals are decreasing. For example, the sequence for $m=4$ is 
$(4)_1=4=2^2$, $(4)_2=26=3^3-1=2\cdot 3^2+2\cdot 3+2$, $(4)_3=41=2\cdot 4^2+2\cdot 4+1$, $(4)_4=60=2\cdot 5^2+2\cdot 5$, $(4)_5=83=2\cdot 6^2+6+5$, etc. The associated sequence of ordinals is $$\omega^\omega>2\cdot \omega^2+2\cdot \omega+2>2\cdot\omega^2+2\cdot \omega+1>2\cdot\omega^2+2\cdot \omega>2\cdot\omega^2+\omega+5>\dots$$
The sequence keeps going for a long time indeed, but it eventually reaches zero, with 
 $$ \mathcal G(4)=3\cdot 2^{402653211}-2.$$

The formula I obtain verifies that Goodstein's function $\mathcal G$ is *fast growing*, in this case meaning that it grows so quickly that given any function $f\!:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ provably total in Peano arithmetic, there is a $k$ such that for all $n\ge k$, $\mathcal G(n)>f(n)$.

Comment: Hello, would you happen to have a link for the paper you provide the reference for at the beginning by Stephen G Simpson? Also I’m trying to read through Goodstein’s paper and so far so good until the author uses a symbol like $\dot{-}$, would you happen to know what that means?

Comment: Hi. There is a very bizarre but apparently faithful transcription of Simpson's paper to raw text at https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=sci.math/KQ4Weqk4TmE/LE_Wfsk00H4J

Comment: The chapter is also accessible at http://www.ams.org/books/conm/065/, depending on your university affiliation. As for the symbol in Goodstein's paper, it stands for truncated subtraction: Given natural numbers $n,m$, $n\dot- m=n-m$ if $n\ge m$, and $n\dot-m=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Probably shouldn’t say thanks, but thank you anyways :) I appreciate the help